# Redis with Symfony2 causes problems between sites on my server

Tags: symfony, redis

I'm using symfony2 snc-redis bundle for caching.

On my server, redis has been installed and working correctly.

My problem is; when i try to clear or flush db with redis, all sites on my server that using redis, crashes. Giving internal server error because of prod env.

I'v tried to change redis configuration ports in my config.yml for every single site on my server but i think didn't work.

My sample snc-redis configuration:

```
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: redis://localhost
            logging: %kernel.debug%
        cache:
            type: predis
            alias: cache
            dsn: redis://localhost/1
            logging: true
        cluster:
            type: predis
            alias: cluster
            dsn:
                - redis://127.0.0.1/5
                - redis://127.0.0.2/6
                - redis://pw@/var/run/redis/redis-1.sock/7
                - redis://127.0.0.1:6379/8
            options:
                profile: 2.4
                connection_timeout: 10
                connection_persistent: true
                read_write_timeout: 30
                iterable_multibulk: false
                throw_errors: true
                cluster: Snc\RedisBundle\Client\Predis\Connection\PredisCluster
        monolog:
            type: predis
            alias: monolog
            dsn: redis://localhost/1
            logging: false
            options:
                connection_persistent: true
    session:
        client: default
        prefix: foo
        use_as_default: true
    doctrine:
        metadata_cache:
            client: cache
            entity_manager: default
            document_manager: default
        result_cache:
            client: cache
            entity_manager: [default, read]
            document_manager: [default, slave1, slave2]
            namespace: "dcrc:"
        query_cache:
            client: cache
            entity_manager: default
    monolog:
        client: monolog
        key: monolog
    swiftmailer:
        client: default
        key: swiftmailer

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: service
            id: monolog.handler.redis
            level: debug
```

What i'm doing wrong? How can i get it work correctly and will not cause crashing.

My Redis Bundle for Symfon2:

> Snc\RedisBundle\SncRedisBundle()

https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define **prefix** for each site like this:

```
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            dsn: "redis://localhost:6379"
            options:
                prefix : "site_name"
            type: phpredis
            alias: default
            logging: %kernel.debug%
```

**Note:** You must to be considered to put this prefix to all clients ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to change client alias for every site ?

Comment: nope. i'v changed cluster > dsn ports for every site. Like : 1, 2, 3, 4